# C# accsess derive method from main..

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

"i try to write progrem with two classes one call "Door" and "AdvanceDoor" (derived class) now AdvanceDoor has function "ChangeCode" , im try to create a  AdvanceDoor object using this syntax:

Door ad = new AdvanceDoor(required prameters...); and i cant see her method (ChangeCode).."

```
    class Program 
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Door ad = new AdvanceDoor(222, 55, "Iron", "223");
          // "here im try to call ChangeCode method from ad and its not exist"

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

now if im write:

```
AdvanceDoor d = new AdvanceDoor(222, 55, "Iron", "223");
```

> this is work... my qustion is why i cant create object using base class then if i pass "new advanceDoor" its give me the advacneDoor options...

Comment: Because the variable `ad` is of type `Door`.  And `Door` doesn't have a `ChangeCode` method.  You can only interact with things which exist on the type you're using.  You could add that method to the parent class, you could use the derived type for your variable, you could cast the variable to the derived type, etc.  But the root of the problem is that your design is broken, and you need to better understand and model the objects you want to use.

Comment: How should the compiler know which kind of `Door` is stored in `ad` at runtime? Maybe you'll have a `NotSoAdvancedDoor` with no `ChangeCode` that you store in `ad`. C# is a language with great *type-safety*. So if you say it's a `Door`, it's only a `Door`, not an `AdvancedDoor`.

Comment: yes but when i declare the base and then the subclass its It should identify  
recognize it as a subclass type isn't it so?

Comment: @ShlomiTubul: The object in memory may be of type `AdvancedDoor`, but the *variable* is of type `Door`.  They are two different things.

Comment: @David ok thank you !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wanted to answer a little bit more in depth:

```
MyBaseClass bob = new SubClass();
bob.OnlyBaseClassMethods();
```

... the reason for this is that the variable bob is only *certain* to be a MyBaseClass.  If it helps, picture this:

```
MyBaseClass bob;
if (something)
    bob = new SubClass();
else
    bob = new SecondSubClass();
bob.OnlyBaseClassMethods();
```

... at this point, bob could be *either* of those subclasses.

So are you out of luck for what you're trying to do?

Depends.  Take a look at this code:

```
public class Door
{
    public void Open() { /* ... code ... */ }
    public void Close() { /* ... code ... */ }
}
public interface PasswordEncoded
{
    void ChangeCode();
}
public class AdvancedDoor : Door, PasswordEncoded
{
    public void ChangeCode() { /* ... code ... */ }
}

// ... elsewhere

public void SomeFunction(Door someDoor)
{
    if (someDoor is PasswordEncoded)
        ((PasswordEncoded)someDoor).ChangeCode();
}
```

What's going on here?  I've added an interface, called "PasswordEncoded".  If you write a class that implements this interface, it *will* have a function called "ChangeCode".

Okay, so you've got a 'Door' variable - you *can't* call ChangeCode as it currently stands.  But you *can* check whether that variable holds an instance that *does* have that ChangeCode function - whether it's something that's PasswordEncoded.

If it does?  Then you can cast it as a PasswordEncoded object (which it is - you just checked for that the line before) and call the ChangeCode() method from there.

Comment: i don't learn about interface... you can explain to me briefly what he does?

Comment: The word "Contract" is sometimes used, but I like the term "Descriptor".  Basically, you identify a bit of functionality that one or more classes will need, and then write an interface for that functionality.  Afterwards, you have those appropriate classes implement that interface (like in my example.)  It's tough to put more detail in a comment, but the concept is very important for writing good, long-term code - you should do some googling to research: "Abstract Class", "Interface", and "Dependency Inversion Principle" to get some more background on it.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access method of specific class but when you are creating object of AdvanceDoor you are assigning it to base class hence the ChangeCode method is not available to your instance.

Right way to do is 
AdvanceDoor d = new AdvanceDoor(222, 55, "Iron", "223");

or create interface instead of base class with all the methods.